# Regular expression to find large numbers in word form

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract numbers in word form from a string. For example, an input string might be something like:

```
"What is 3 million 6 hundred 5 divided by 5 hundred?"
```

From this input, I'd like to figure out how to get the two numbers as groups.

```
["3 million 6 hundred 5", "5 hundred"]
```

*Note: It is possible that there could be more numbers found in other input strings.*

I believe regex is the correct route to solve this problem. Ideally I could pass in a list of the scales such as:

```
["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", ...]
```

So far this is what I have:

```
scales= ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion"]
scale_pattern = '|'.join(scales)
regex = re.compile('\b(d+' + scale_pattern + 'd+)+\b')
```

I know my pattern isn't quite right, the psudeocode for what I'm going for is:

```
for any number of the following occurrences:
    find the pattern [int word_from_list optional_int]
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of votes are coming in fast to close this question. Any feedback on what I could to to improve it?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sure, thank you. I'll update it with what I have so far.

Comment: You could try an attempt and then ask question. I tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/A5iiWc/1).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ideally I could pass in a list of the scales

You can pass them in non-capturing or capturing group like this.

**Regex:** `(?:\d+\s(?:million|hundred|thousand|billion)*\s*)+`

Above is a simple regex checking for a number `\d+` followed by a whitespace `\s` and **scale** which is **optional** (by using `*` quantifier) for last number followed by optional whitespace. And the whole pattern repeated **one or many** times (by using `+` quantifier).

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A5iiWc/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, below is an inferior parser.

```
# you should expand these lists later...
units = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion"]
operations = ['divided', 'multiplied']
delims = ['by', 'with']
discards = ['?', '!', '.']

sentence = 'What is 3 million 6 hundred 5 divided by 5 hundred?'

filterd_sentence = sentence
for t in discards:
    filterd_sentence = filterd_sentence.replace(t, '')

filterd_t = []
buffer = ''
for t in filterd_sentence.split(' '):
    if t.isnumeric() or t in units:
        buffer += t + ' '
    elif t in operations or t in delims:
        if buffer != '':
            filterd_t.append(buffer[:len(buffer)-1])
            buffer = ''

if buffer != '':
    filterd_t.append(buffer[:len(buffer)-1])

print(filterd_t)
# ['3 million 6 hundred 5', '5 hundred']
```